# Pandas str match for German addresses

Tags: regex, pandas, geocoding, nominatim

I have a quite annoying problem in designing a regex to prepare addresses for geocoding with Nominatim. I am working with German addresses which look like this:

```
Von-der-Leyen-Platz 1 47506 Neukirchen-Vluyn    
Schildstraße 52531 Übach-Palenberg  
Finkenratherstraße Straße 4a 52134 Herzogenrath 
Format: Street Number Postal code City
```

What I want to achieve is that first literals after street numbers do not occur. For this I am using the following regex:

```
(\d+).*?\s+(.+)
```

It is matching the third address to 4 52134 Herzogenrath. But not to Finkenratherstraße 4 52143 Herzogenrath. Another problem I saw is the second address as it does not have a street number. That is why I wanted to filter create a regex which can filter for the following structure:

```
Street name {number if available} Postal code (5 digits) City name
```

The postal code always has 5 digits and the structure is always the same just that sometimes the street number is missing.

Is there any way to design this as a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your data, this could work:

```
# sample data
s = pd.Series(['Von-der-Leyen-Platz 1 47506 Neukirchen-Vluyn',
               'Schildstraße 52531 Übach-Palenberg',
               'Finkenratherstraße Straße 4a 52134 Herzogenrath'])

# extract
s.str.extract(r'(?P<Street>\D+)\s?(?P<Number>\d+\S*)?\s(?P<Postal>\d{5})\s(?P<City>\D+)$')
```

Output:

```
                      Street Number Postal              City
0        Von-der-Leyen-Platz     1   47506  Neukirchen-Vluyn
1               Schildstraße    NaN  52531   Übach-Palenberg
2  Finkenratherstraße Straße    4a   52134      Herzogenrath
```